# How to set up a loop in csh to set variables to directory names?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, csh

My file structure is like this.

```
unix% ls
NGC2201 IC0499 IC7216 NGC7169
unix% cd NGC2201
unix% ls
7019 2221 note
```

where 7019 and 2221 are new directories and note is a text file that I use to create variables. The contents within 2221 and 7019 are important, but do not need to be set as variables; my scripts afterwords will take care of all of that.

My current script is the following:

```
# The purpose of this script is to take the note files provided and set the values as variables.

#!/bin/csh -f

set z=`grep -E '^z=' note | cut -d= -f2`
set nh=`grep 'NH' note | cut -d= -f2`
set xc=`grep 'Center' note | cut -d, -f1 | cut '-d' -f4`


echo $z $nh $xc
```

This sets three variables for use in the current directory (in this case, we will use NGC2201 as the parent directory and 7019 and 2221 as the sub-directories for these variables to be used on).

My question is how do I write a script to automatically set NGC2201 as a variable named $g and 2221 as a variable named $obs.

After the script runs through 2221, I would like it to then set the directory as 7019 and repeat the steps. After the directories within NGC2201 are finished, I would like the script to move on to IC0499, repeat the process, etc.

How do I get the script to run through the directories? I cannot make it global because it cannot be too intrusive; I need it to only go two directories deep to be satisfactory.

I would like to keep it within csh if possible, but if this is easier in tcsh or bash, I am all for it. Additionally, if there is an easier solution than looping it like this, I am all for that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `csh`, you can use a `foreach` loop to loop over every subdirectory of the directories in the current directory:

```
foreach i (*/*/)
  set g=`echo $i | cut -d/ -f1`   # slash-delimited, select first field
  set obs=`echo $i | cut -d/ -f2` # slash-delimited, select second field
  echo $g $obs
end
```

The `bash` equivalent is a `for` loop. Of course you can use `cut` as above, but `bash` also has an elaborated [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) feature, so you don’t need to call anything external:

```
for i in */*/; do
  g=${i%%/*}   # cut everything from the first slash 
  obs=${i#*/}  # cut everything until first slash
  obs=${obs%/} # cut slash at the end
  echo $g $obs
done
```

Substitute the `echo` line with whatever you want to do with the variables.

#### Example run

`%` is the `csh` prompt, `$` the `bash` one.

```
% tree    
.
├── IC0499
├── IC7216
│   └── 2222
├── NGC2201
│   ├── 2221
│   ├── 7019
│   └── note
└── NGC7169

7 directories, 1 file

% foreach i (*/*/)
? set g=`echo $i | cut -d/ -f1`
? set obs=`echo $i | cut -d/ -f2`
? echo $g $obs
? end
IC7216 2222
NGC2201 2221
NGC2201 7019

$ for i in */*/; do g=${i%%/*}; obs=${i#*/}; obs=${obs%/}; echo $g $obs; done
IC7216 2222
NGC2201 2221
NGC2201 7019
```

Citing https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/csh-shell-scripting-loop-example/:

> Please note that `csh` was popular for many innovative features but `csh` has never been as popular for scripting. If you are writing system level rc scripts avoid using `csh`. You may want to use `/bin/sh` for any scripts that might have to run on other systems.